# Achieving reliable UDP connectivity

Tags: c++, networking, udp

We're been developing software that is very network-heavy, and to minimize latency we're using UDP sockets for much of the network communication. However, whenever we deploy our platform in an 'unknown' location - for example when demoing the software, we run into trouble getting all the networking to actually work. We're not incompotent with setting up routers, but I'm sure there must be some way we're missing in how to properly implement these sockets.

Basically, we use a system like this:

- At the core, we use the Unreal Engine, which has its own implementation of networking (which we partly use). Unreal Engine uses ports 7777 UDP and TCP, and we have these ports forwarded on our dedicated server's router.
- We use custom UDP sockets on another port. We also have these forwarded on the dedicated server's route.

Now the thing I do not understand is this: The unreal engine UDP protocol always seems to function correctly on clients (that have no specific forwarding enabled), while our custom socket sometimes fails to receive data: that is, in some networks it works problemlessly, in others it doesn't work (no data is received by the clients)

Some of the things we've tried are setting up a TCP connection between the client and the server on the same port, which does connect but does not always 'fix' the disconnectivity of the same UDP port. Another thing I've tried is NAT hole punching, but this also doesn't seem to always work.

My question is: How do programs like unreal engine (and other programs, e.g. ones that use VoIP) 'guarantee' their UDP networking works? I would love to get some pointers about techniques I might try to use.

Thanks!

Comment: VoIP doesn't need a guarantee from UDP; it accepts some loss. UDP is a connectionless, unreliable, fire-and-forget protocol. If you need reliability with UDP, your application needs to provide for that.

Comment: if a NAT/router supports uPNP, port forwarding rules can be enabled programmably by network apps without requiring an admin to do it manually.

Comment: there used to be an IP protocol called RDP - Reliable Datagram Protocol. Is that still a thing?

Comment: My goal is not to reduce packet loss or anything, my goal is setting up a working connection in the first place - and preferably in a reliable way

Comment: What kind of custom UDP sockets you combine with UE4? I know some libraries provide reliable UDP functionalities, is there official documentation in Unreal that mentions they don't provide reliable UDP connections? I know they have reliable RPCs, but the details in their doc are shallow.